# The use of "r+" in fopen on windows vs linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, file-io, fopen

I was toying around with some code which was opening, reading, and modifying a text file. A quick (simplified) example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE * fp = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
    char line[100] = {'\0'};
    int count = 0;
    int ret_code = 0;
    while(!feof(fp)){
        fgets(line, 100, fp);
        // do some processing on line...
        count++;
        if(count == 4) {
          ret_code = fprintf(fp, "replaced this line\n");
          printf("ret code was %d\n", ret_code);
          perror("Error was: ");
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Now on Linux, compiled with gcc (4.6.2) this code runs, and modifies the file's 5th line. The same code, running on Windows7 compiled with Visual C++2010 runs and claims to have succeeded (reports a return code of 19 characters and `perror` says "No error") but fails to replace the line.

On Linux my file has full permissions:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mike users 191 Feb 14 10:11 test.txt
```

And as far as I can tell it's the same on Windows:

test.txt (right click) -> properties -> Security 
"Allow" is checked for Read & Write for user, System, and Admin.

I get the same results using MinGW's gcc on Windows so I know it's not a Visual C++ "feature".

Am I missing something obvious, or is the fact that I get no errors, but also no output just an undocumented "feature" of using `r+` with `fopen()` on Windows?

---

**EDIT:** 
Seems even at [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(v=vs.71).aspx) they say "r+" should open for reading *and* writting. They also made this note:

> When the "r+", "w+", or "a+" access type is specified, both reading and writing are allowed (the file is said to be open for "update"). However, when you switch between reading and writing, there must be an intervening fflush, fsetpos, fseek, or rewind operation. The current position can be specified for the fsetpos or fseek operation, if desired.

So I tried:

```
        ...
        if(count == 4) {
          fflush(fp);
          ret_code = fprintf(fp, "replaced this line\n");
          fflush(fp);
          printf("ret code was %d\n", ret_code);
          ...
```

to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the stream using `fflush` after the write operation?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the issue, but you might need to call `fseek` when switching between reading and writing from the file

Comment: @KristerAndersson - yup, just updated to clarify I saw the note at the MSDN site that says you should update the stream by one of the `f<operations>()` so i tried `fflush()`ing before and after the write, but no dice.

Comment: @Mike: Try fclosing your file stream before the program exits.

Comment: @Mike - Could it have something to do with the linefeed? I think windows uses `\r\n` will linux uses `\n`

Comment: I just tried that on Windows 7 with cygwin/gcc, and it'S appending the line to the end of file (after outputting ret code was 19). You should call perror only when result is negative.

Comment: @SecurityMatt - `fclose()` was already in there, when I was transcribing the my code I forgot to copy that over, updated now.

Comment: @Hasturkun - Wow, that was it... want to post that as an answer and I'll accept for you? The code that fixed it was `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);` instead of the `fflush(fp);`

Comment: Aside from your output problem: `while(!feof(fp))` is an antipattern for reading a file. See http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html and http://drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2 This antipattern will cause your program to loop more than you might expect when reading the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Linux man page for `fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen):

> Reads and writes may be intermixed on read/write streams in any order.
>   Note that ANSI C requires that a file positioning function intervene
>   between output and input, unless an input operation encounters
>   end-of-file. (If this condition is not met, then a read is allowed to
>   return the result of writes other than the most recent.) Therefore it
>   is good practice (and indeed sometimes necessary under Linux) to put
>   an fseek(3) or fgetpos(3) operation between write and read operations
>   on such a stream. This operation may be an apparent no-op (as in
>   fseek(..., 0L, SEEK_CUR) called for its synchronizing side effect.

So, you should always call `fseek()` (as, eg. `fseek(..., 0, SEEK_CUR)`) when switching between reading and writing from a file.

Comment: That was the problem, and that's what I get for reading the MSDN documentation instead of the man page. :) thanks.

Comment: Note that the mosty recent docs from MSDN (for VS 2012) has been updated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx

Comment: @MichaelBurr - Good point, that wasn't the most recent documentation, I should update my bookmark, been a while since I've been there.

Answer (score 3):

Before performing output after input, an `fflush()` isn't any good - you need to perform a seek operation.  Something like:

```
fseek(fp, ftell(fp), SEEK_SET); // not fflush(fp);
```

from the C99 standard (7.19.5.3/6 "The fopen functoin):

> When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third
>   character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and
>   output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output
>   shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to
>   the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek,
>   fsetpos, or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output
>   without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the
>   input operation encounters end-of-file.

Comment: It's funny, you say "fflush() isn't any good" but then the C99 snippet you quoted says: `without an intervening call to the fflush function OR to a file positioning function`. So, right there it says either `fflush()` OR `fseek()`/other positioning functions.

Comment: That's for output followed by input.  Your problem was in performing input followed by output, which needs an intervening file positioning call (or EOF).  I will say that this is kind of tricky to read to get all the conditions straight in your head - a table would work better.

Comment: +1 got it, that makes sence why the ordering matters. Thanks for that input.