# seekp before writing?

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to read and write an binary file with a single file stream. The following code tries to read the first part of the file, and uses it to overwrite the second part of the file. But I find that I have to use "seekp(pos [,ios_base::begin]);" before writing. Additionally, "seekp" in fact doesn't change the position in my code, but it is necessary! Could any one give an explain? It should better be according to the c++ standard. Thanks very much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    fstream flib ("tmp.txt", ios::in | ios::out |ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    if(!flib){
        cerr << "file open failed!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    int tmp;

    for(int i = 0; i<2 ; i++){//write 2 numbers
        flib.write((char*)&i, sizeof(tmp));
    }
    flib.seekg(0);
    while(flib.read((char*)&tmp, sizeof(tmp))){//read file contents
        cout <<tmp<<endl; 
    }
    flib.clear();
    flib.seekg(0);
    flib.read((char*)&tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    flib.seekp(sizeof(tmp)); //work
    //flib.seekp(sizeof(tmp), ios_base::beg); //work
    //flib.seekp(0, ios_base::cur); //not work
    //flib.seekp(sizeof(tmp), ios_base::end); //not work
    //flib.seekp(-sizeof(tmp), ios_base::end); //not work
    flib.write((char*)&tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    flib.clear();
    flib.seekg(0);
    while(flib.read((char*)&tmp, sizeof(tmp))){//read file contents
        cout <<tmp<<endl; 
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I find that if I use flib.seekp(some_number, ios_base::cur); with nonzero some_number, it works. And I use vs2012 express compiler, is it a bug?

Comment: And what exactly is `flib.seekp(0, ios_base::cur)` supposed to do? And `flib.seekp(sizeof(tmp), ios_base::end);` shouldn't work because you're trying to seek *past the end*.

Comment: "flib.seekp(0, ios_base::cur)" should be equivalent to "flib.seekp(sizeof(tmp));", right? "flib.seekp(sizeof(tmp), ios_base::end);" may be wrong, but why doesn't "flib.seekp(-sizeof(tmp), ios_base::end);" work?

Comment: It's necessary because the standard says so. Any time you switch from reading to writing or vice versa (of the same file) you need to do a seek or rewind in between. I believe it's mostly to give it a chance to flush buffered data, but I haven't looked through the relevant code recently enough to be sure.

Comment: `flib.seekp(0, ios_base::cur)` says "seek zero bytes from the current position" so it should effectively do nothing (so it's not the same as `flib.seekp(sizeof(tmp))`, which says "move to this absolute position" (it's like `flib.seekp(sizeof(tmp), ios_base::beg)`)). As for the `flib.seekp(-sizeof(tmp), ios_base::end)`, we would have to see exactly how you're calling it, because it [Works For Me](http://ideone.com/z0abRh)

Comment: @ Cornstalks When I use "flib.seekp(-sizeof(tmp), ios_base::end);", the following while loop would be infinite... It seems the "-sizeof(tmp)" is convert to a large positive integer.

Comment: @user Yeah, size types are unsigned. Use `-(int)sizeof(tmp)` or `-(long)sizeof(tmp)`.

Comment: @us2012 Thank you! That works! So, if I don't know the absolute position, how can I do? I don't want to move some position then move back...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File streams use a `basic_filebuf<>` for the stream buffer.  The C++03 standard has this to say about `class basic_filebuf<charT,traits>`:

> 27.8.1.1 Class tempate basic_filebuf
>
> The class basic_filebuf associates both the input
>   sequence and the output sequence with a file.
>
> The restrictions on reading and writing a sequence controlled by an
>   object of class basic_filebuf are the same as for
>   reading and writing with the Standard C library `FILE`s.
>
> In particular:
>     - If the file is not open for reading the input sequence cannot be read.
>     - If the file is not open for writing the output sequence cannot be written.
>     - A joint file position is maintained for both the input sequence and the output sequence.

Unfortunately it doesn't call out that when transitioning between reading and writing to a `FILE` object using the standard C library, you have to perform a file positioning call (or an `fflush()` when transitioning from write operations to read operations).  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879076/12711.